# How prevent MissingMethodException or TypeLoadException or how recover DLL coruption in NETCF (wince)?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I have netcf program install in NAND flash of WinCE (I don't control wince build).
Normally it works, but if user turn on/off randomly my exe or dll files corrupt and I got MissingMethodException or TypeLoadException. How to recover this dll corruption?

Or sometime if I save *.ini file , suddenly user turn off power after that *.ini file can not open, copy, delete so it fire WinIOException. Anyone encounter like this before? Where is raw file store in WinCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with your file system. Wich version of WinCE are you using? On CE 6.0 and newer versions you can use exFAT and have redundant file tables, this should improve the FS reliability and protect you against unespected power-downs. You may also consider running the ScanVolumeEx function on your partition after an unexpected reboot. This must be done before the partition is actually mounted (or you need to un-mount and re-mount it afterwards).

Comment: thanks, I use wince 5.0. How can I re-access file if this file look like lock or FAT system corrupt. As I check other text files can access. Only last file in writing state that power turn off can not access.

Comment: On CE 5.0 you may use TFAT but you still need to do a scan of your FS at boot to ensure that all the errors are fixed and they don't accumulate over time. Depending on when you're writing you may corrupt a single file or a whole folder (if you've a power down when the system is updating the file allocation table). You can't regognize a corrupted file, you can only recognize a corrupted FS by doing a scan.